# Progress bar button in HTML5

Tags: html

I would like to combine two features of HTML5 into one.  I am trying to essentially make a progress bar button on a page.  The progress bar does not need to be updated on the page, only when the page is refreshed will the bar change position.  Any idea how I could do this?

Thanks

-Jesse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `<div>` within a `<div>` would do the job? And just set the style of the inner `<div>` as a %.

The [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/) also provides an elegant solution.

Comment: Great suggestion.  Any idea how I could make that into a click able button though?

Comment: Just add a jquery click event on it? Then you could do whatever you wanted, submit a form, a link or whatever.

Comment: Excellent, and one last question.  I have been trying to place Text on top of the progress bar but I am not really getting it to work.  It keeps pushing the shaded section down and not really putting the text on top of the whole progress bar.  Would you have any experience with this?  

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="window.alert('Clicked');">
    <progress max="1.0" value="0.7">70%</progress>
</button>
```

[Seems to work in Opera & Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/Z4AWQ/), it also works OK in Firefox but no support for `progress`.